# Laravel - Send an email when a number reaches a certain level

Tags: laravel

I would like to be able to send an email to a user as soon as a number is reached in the database (this number is found thanks to a calculation)
Example: I buy for 1 month, the possibility to use 100 times an API, and after 80% of consumption, I receive an email to warn me.

I could do it very badly, by putting a condition to each use of the api, which checks if we reach the 80% or not.

But for me there is another cleaner method to do it, do you have any ideas? Wouldn't it be in relation to events?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use Laravel [scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling) to do it ; for example check that number every day or hour(depends on your case) and if that number is 80 or more send the email (that to you can do it using Laravel [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues) for better performances )

Comment: The concern is that it should be instantaneous, so that the user is informed in real time of the 80% reached.
If it's every day, and he receives the mail 6 hours after having exceeded 80%, it's not very consistent.
But I don't see any other way than with Task scheduling, and every hour it's still ok.

Comment: You can even do it every 5 minutes (But you have to choose the best period for you for performance reasons)

Comment: Ok I see, and it consumes a lot of this kind of thing? I admit I have no idea. And in terms of cleanliness, it's better to do that, and that it's a little bit off, or add the condition that checks in the controller ?

Comment: If you get all users and add them to the queue(https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues) and let the queue job handle that; I don't think it will be heavy.

Comment: Ok I see a little bit better how to do all this, thank you very much for your help! See you soon ;)